# How to make hero slider go to a specific slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using [Hero Slider](http://codyhouse.co/gem/hero-slider/) for my project, and I want to define a function like `gotoSlideN(n)` to go to the nth slide.

```
var gotoSlideN = function (n) {
  $(".cd-hero-slider .selected").removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function () {
    $(".cd-hero-slider .selected").removeClass('is-moving');
  });
  var selectedPosition = n,
      activePosition = $('.cd-hero-slider .selected').index();
  if (activePosition < selectedPosition) {
    $(".cd-hero-slider").children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-left').nextAll().addClass('move-left');
  } else {
    $(".cd-hero-slider").children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-left').prevAll().addClass('move-right');
  }
};
```

The code above works but it got some issues when I try to go previous slides. 
For example, when I call `gotoSlideN(3)`, when the selected slide is number 4, the 4th slide goes hidden but the 3rd slide doesn't show.

```
gotoSlideN(5); //working
gotoSlideN(4); //working
gotoSlideN(5); //not working truly
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question

```
enter code herevar gotoSlideN = function (n) {var selectedPosition = n,
        activePosition = $('.cd-hero-slider .selected').index();
if (activePosition < selectedPosition) {
$(".cd-hero-slider .selected").removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function () {
    $(".cd-hero-slider .selected").removeClass('is-moving');
});
   $(".cd-hero-slider").children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-left').nextAll().addClass('move-left');
} 
else {
    $(".cd-hero-slider .selected").removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
  $(".cd-hero-slider .selected").removeClass('is-moving');
});  
   $(".cd-hero-slider").children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-left').removeClass('move-left').nextAll().removeClass('move-left');
```

//       container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-left').removeClass('move-left').nextAll().removeClass('move-left');
    }
};